# Disabling button functionality if any fields are empty in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Are Name and Age null if there are no inputs in the EditText field when the App runs? Also, I can't seem to get the conditional syntax down. Any tips? I'm new to Kotlin.

```
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button4)
    button.setOnClickListener {

        when{
            Name.val==null && Age.val==null && gender.val=="" -> button.isEnabled=false
        }
        val intent = Intent(this, fourth::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
```

}

Comment: what is Name and Age, its class or edittext?

Comment: They're edittext

Comment: what id for both name and age?

Comment: can you attach detail about Name and Age?